# How to find and remove repeated words from sentence in PowerPoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I find and remove repeated words from sentences in PowerPoint?

As a grammar check I want to find double words which are typed by mistake. For example:

> Stackoverflow is **a a** greate site

In this example, one "a" would be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend, you are embarking on a dangerous mission if you are trying to re-invent automatic grammar checking. Natural language is filled with exceptions guaranteed to evade whatever small set of rules you think will do the job.

Anyhow, below is a lucidly naive stab at it. Now, this code works for the example you gave. It will remove that extra "a". But please be aware that not every repeated word should be removed if you care about preserving grammar, syntax and semantics. Automatically removing repeated "that"s will work wonders on this:

> I love that that site.

but it will alter the writer's intent on this by taking the grammar down to a very informal level:

> She said that that is a great site.

and removing repeats will ruin absolutely everything here:

> [That that is is that that is not is not that that is that that is is not true is not true.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_that_is_is_that_that_is_not_is_not_is_that_it_it_is)

not to mention this:

> [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Be prepared for disaster! But anyway, the code works for your example (and more) and provides a framework for you to build upon and to fine-tune such that it works in the majority of cases relevant to you.

```
Dim shp As Shape
Dim str As String
Dim wordArr() As String
Dim words As Collection
Dim iWord As Long
Dim thisWord As String
Dim nextWord As String
Dim newText As String

For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
        'Get the text
        str = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        'Split it into an array of words
        wordArr = Split(str, " ")

        'Transfer to a Collection, easier to deal with than array.
        Set words = New Collection
        For iWord = LBound(wordArr) To UBound(wordArr)
            words.Add wordArr(iWord)
        Next iWord

        'Look for repeats.
        For iWord = words.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
            thisWord = words.Item(iWord)
            nextWord = words.Item(iWord + 1)

            'Make sure commas don't get in the way of a comparison
            'e.g. "This is a great, great site" is fine
            'but "This site is great great, and I love it" is not.
            nextWord = Replace(nextWord, ",", "")
            'Add whatever other filtering you feel is appropriate.
            'e.g. period, case sensitivity, etc.

            If LCase(thisWord) = LCase(nextWord) Then
                If LCase(thisWord) = "that" Then
                    'Do nothing. "He said that that was great." is ok.
                    'This is just an example. "had" is another.
                    'Add more filtering here.
                Else
                    words.Remove iWord + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next iWord

        'Assemble the text with repeats removed.
        newText = ""
        For iWord = 1 To words.Count
            newText = newText & words.Item(iWord) & " "
        Next iWord

        'Finally, put it back on the slide.
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = newText
    End If
Next shp
```

Comment: If you refine this then for each shape its probably better to grab all the text from all items and place them in a single string called paragraph. Remove any commas. Perform a split on any periods (".") into another array called sentences. Then do the side by side test for each two word next to each other that are separated by a space in each sentence.

Comment: You raise a good point that certain doubled up words may be ok, so a modification prompting user input for these inputs would be useful. While your code certainly works (I did test it) and is logically designed it is taking a much longer path than a readymade parsing tool.

Comment: @brettdj: I agree that a regex would be much more concise, but would it not become completely cryptic and unreadable once you add all the required natural language exception handling?

Comment: It certainly gets harder. I presume that Word and Outlook use a similar regexp to what I put forward below to *flag* potential issues. Perhaps running a `RegExp` report on potential issues for the user to consider in the same manner is a better appraoch than a direct change.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic `RegExp` application that can remove all repeated words in a single shot (rather than looping word by word) using backreferences.

Note if you want detailed help in accessing the underlying PPT text then you will need to provide more information as to where in the slide(s) the text occurs

```
Sub TestString()
    MsgBox ReducedText("stackoverflow stackoverflow Stackoverflow is a a great site")
End Sub

Function ReducedText(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\b(\w+)\b(\s+\1\b)+"
        ReducedText = .Replace(strIn, "$1")
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

regular expression makes this nice and easy

```
Function remove_duplicates()

    txt = "Stackoverflow is a a greate site"

    Set word_match = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    word_match.IgnoreCase = True
    word_match.Global = True

    For Each wrd In Split(txt, " ")
        word_match.Pattern = wrd & " " & wrd
        txt = word_match.Replace(txt, wrd)
    Next

    MsgBox txt

End Function
```

Comment: I'm no RegExp expert, but I'm pretty sure that this is not a particularly good way to use it...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett that's funny because above you said above _I'll have to learn RegExp at some point_. 

Thanks for the opinion on regex - guy who doesn't know regex!

Comment: Aren't we in a sarcastic mood... Your use of regex is basically a roundabout way of emulating the native VBA `Replace` function: it is exactly equivalent to `txt = Replace(txt, wrd & " " & wrd, wrd)`.  So yeah, I know enough to see that your use of regex adds no particular benefit, only complexity.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett you got me.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Valid comment on the both the `RegExp` usuage and shared learning.